# Math comparison operating in Django templates

Tags: math, django-templates, counter

i want to compare do simple math in django template

like {% forloop.counter > 5 %}
     {% endfor %}

how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [`if` tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if) in Django 1.2

```
{% for blip in blah %}
    {% if forloop.counter > 5 %}
    {# Do somthing #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are still using an earlier version of Django then you can check out the smart if tag on djangosnippets: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/

Comment: I am using Django .96 with google app engine and it does not work there

Comment: Sorry. I see now the snippet is for Django 1.0 or higher.