# Math comparison operating in Django .96 templates

Tags: math, django-templates

i want to compare do simple math in django template

like {% forloop.counter > 5 %} {% endfor %}

how do i achieve this?

Comment: Close: possible duplicate of [Math comparison operating in Django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148350/math-comparison-operating-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible, because Django deliberately provides a very limited syntax, which doesn't include math operators. You could do this by [writing a custom template filter](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates_python/#writing-custom-template-filters), but it's a poor idea - you'd be better off preprocessing the data before passing it in so you don't require the math operator. That's certainly what Django wants you to do, anyway.